# Laravel eloquent relationship with order by child

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The query that is currently being executed for displaying the listing page is as follows:

```php
$q = RunningCars::query();
$q->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
          ->orWhere('start_date', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
})
  ->where('last_day_end_time', '>=', strtotime('now'))
  ->where('pause_status', '<>', TRUE);
$q->with('give', 'want', 'favourite_car_list')->paginate(10);
```

The relationship described in the modal is as follows:

```php
public function favourite_car_list() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FavouriteScripts', 'script_id', 'id')
                ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
}
```

If I try to sort the scripts according to the favourite scripts table I will have to implement the following

```php
$q->with('give', 'want', 'favourite_car_list')
  ->orderBy('favourite_car_list.is_favourite');
```

But `orderBy()` does not get implemented on with statement on child array.

Can you help me on how I can do order by in eloquent?

Comment: Are you trying to order parents by child relationships? Or order just childs?

Comment: @lamzozo order parents by child relationship.

Comment: You need joins. Eloquent cannot do this functionality by itself.

Comment: @Hkan - Can you suggest on how I can achieve it?

Comment: Join the necessary tables, and add `->orderBy('table.column', 'asc');`

Comment: @Hkan - If I use join, I will have to rewrite the complete eloquent model and it's views. Because join query return array whereas eloquent returns objects.

Comment: Well, I honestly don't remember if it returns array instead of Eloquent Collection when you use joins but this is not the concern of this question. You asked, I proposed a solution. The consequences are yours to be concerned.